# How to get my windows docs ; pics, mp3, and docs off an external usb hard drive (sata 3.5 enclosure)

Tags: windows, external-hdd, sata

Back when I had windows 7, I cloned my internal hard drive to an enclosed external usb hard drive. I then formatted my internal hard drive and installed ubuntu 11.10 as my only OS. How do I migrate my files, pics, mp3's, and etc off the external drive and back to my internal drive which now only has ubuntu on it. (and why is this process not made easier?)

I have tried logging in as the root user but I cannot find the external device. I have downloaded several different apps to manage files, usb sticks and etc. PLEASE HELP!!!

****additional info*****

I cloned in win7 with a program called "xxclone" i also used the option to make it bootable, which did not work apparently. I also should note that at the time of the disk cloning, I had a live version of ubuntu 11.10 on it in what I think is a dual boot mode. (where you have the option of which OS to run at start-up)

When I plug the drive enclosure into a friends pc that has windows, I can see all my files, non-hidden system files, and etc. The drive is just not bootable by itself. (ie. when I take out my internal harddrive, change bios order, and attempt to boot with only the external hard drive) The laptop just cycles through from the HP logo (I think thats what a "post is) to windows cannot start, launch startup repair, to insert windows installation disk or contact system administrator, back to HP screen.

I wonder if I could take the external drive and try to install ubuntu off a usb stick, if I could run it in a dual boot, and some how transfer my files. My original, internal drive got accedently formatted, however ,when I was trying to partition it for an install of ubuntu several days ago.

I realized my not so smart mistake and I'm sure it'll make some of you laugh! In my first attempt to install ubuntu; that resulted in a formatted hard drive, I installed a disk image of ubuntu, not on a usb flash drive, but on the drive I intended to install the OS.  learning is so fun :(

**The command** `lsusb` **returns the following:**

> bambos@bambos-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:~$ `lsusb`
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:241d Hewlett-Packard Gobi 2000 Wireless Modem (QDL mode)
>   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
>   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 090c:137b Feiya Technology Corp.
>   Bus 002 Device 014: ID 2109:3431
>   Bus 002 Device 015: ID 0bda:0301 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
>   Bus 002 Device 016: ID 1ca1:18a9

Nothing happens when I plug it in to my laptop and turn on the enclosure. I did however find 2 icons in "Computer" named Generic USB 3.0 CRW (1 and 2). But I am unable to open them.

My enclosure is a rocketfish 3.5 sata enclosure and has a 3.0USB connector. I Have 2 usb ports on my laptop and as far as I know, they are both working. (Installed ubuntu off a usb 4GB stick, and have a USB keyboard working.

**It's interesting that I can plug a usb wireless mouse into a usb port located ON THE ENCLOSURE itself, and the mouse works.**

Comment: So, just plugging the External drive doesn't do anything? does `lsbusb` shows anything?

Comment: How did you clone it? If you used a specific program it is highly probable that you should use it again to "unclone" the disk and reveal the files inside the copy.

Comment: You shouldn't need to log in as root to accomplish this.  In fact, this is likely to hamper your efforts to connect to the external drive.

Comment: I just added some additional info to my post.

Comment: can you expand on your phrase "But I am unable to open them."?  Do you get a specific error?

Comment: It does not do anything when I double-click. When I go into disk manager and mount the volume, it says no media detected. there are 2 partitions detected.

Comment: Here's a new train of thought.... Is there a free program like Nfts veiwer, that I could burn to a cd or put on a usb stick that would be OS independent, and self-bootable? I could transfer the data files, or export them with this. (the program im talking about is http://www.ntfs.com/bootdisk_quest_editions.htm but it's 80 dollars and I'm not sure if the trial verision would let me copy the files)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

chances are it is the device you are using to link the external to the Ubuntu drive. I had it happen to me when I was trying to get this to work. Check the specs of the thing you are using to link them as I would be willing to bet it would only work windows to windows, mac to mac, windows to mac, or mac to windows. Best of luck

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the enclosure itself: It's either extremely rare, or never happens, than a drive enclosure only supports specific operating systems. If the OS supports USB and the disk, and the enclosure supports the disk, and it doesn't work, it's not an OS-enclosure compatibility problem.